# Parsing data in angular typeahead component not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am using AngularJS Bootstrap typeahead component to display data from an array of objects. The problem is that i keep on getting the following error even though my data is being return from my api call.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

Here is what the controller looks like at the moment.

```
$scope.companySearch = function(val) {
    LeadsService.getCompany(val)
        .then(function(resp) {
            return resp.resp;
        });
};
```

and the directive

```
 <input typeahead="company as item.company_name for item in companySearch($viewValue)" id="companyName" name="company_name" type="text" class="form-control input-md" ng-model="companyDetails.company_name" typeahead-wait-ms="200" required>
```

Finally her is the data that im trying to fetch;

```
[{"id":2,"company_name":"Test Company","address1":"abc","address2":"def","po_box":"1234","city_id":2,"email":"lklk@lklk.com","phone":"9898","fax_no":9798,"website":"www.jgjh.com","corporate_code":null,"contact_person_first_name":"First","contact_person_last_name":"Last","contact_person_phone":"98989","contact_person_email":"kjskdjk@kjdkaj.com"},{"id":3,"company_name":"Test Company","address1":"abc","address2":"def","po_box":"1234","city_id":2,"email":"lklk@lklk.com","phone":"9898","fax_no":9798,"website":"www.jgjh.com","corporate_code":null,"contact_person_first_name":"First","contact_person_last_name":"Last","contact_person_phone":"98989","contact_person_email":"kjskdjk@kjdkaj.com"},{"id":4,"company_name":"Test Company","address1":"abc","address2":"def","po_box":"1234","city_id":2,"email":"lklk@lklk.com","phone":"9898","fax_no":9798,"website":"www.jgjh.com","corporate_code":"17","contact_person_first_name":"First","contact_person_last_name":"Last","contact_person_phone":"98989","contact_person_email":"kjskdjk@kjdkaj.com"},{"id":5,"company_name":"Test Company","address1":"abc","address2":"def","po_box":"1234","city_id":2,"email":"lklk@lklk.com","phone":"9898","fax_no":9798,"website":"www.jgjh.com","corporate_code":"17","contact_person_first_name":"First","contact_person_last_name":"Last","contact_person_phone":"98989","contact_person_email":"kjskdjk@kjdkaj.com"},{"id":6,"company_name":"Test Company","address1":"abc","address2":"def","po_box":"1234","city_id":2,"email":"lklk@lklk.com","phone":"9898","fax_no":9798,"website":"www.jgjh.com","corporate_code":"18","contact_person_first_name":"First","contact_person_last_name":"Last","contact_person_phone":"98989","contact_person_email":"kjskdjk@kjdkaj.com"},{"id":7,"company_name":"Test Company","address1":"abc","address2":"def","po_box":"1234","city_id":2,"email":"lklk@lklk.com","phone":"9898","fax_no":9798,"website":"www.jgjh.com","corporate_code":"19","contact_person_first_name":"First","contact_person_last_name":"Last","contact_person_phone":"98989","contact_person_email":"kjskdjk@kjdkaj.com"},{"id":8,"company_name":"Test Company","address1":"abc","address2":"def","po_box":"1234","city_id":2,"email":"lklk@lklk.com","phone":"9898","fax_no":9798,"website":"www.jgjh.com","corporate_code":"20","contact_person_first_name":"First","contact_person_last_name":"Last","contact_person_phone":"98989","contact_person_email":"kjskdjk@kjdkaj.com"},{"id":9,"company_name":"Test Company","address1":"abc","address2":"def","po_box":"1234","city_id":2,"email":"lklk@lklk.com","phone":"9898","fax_no":9798,"website":"www.jgjh.com","corporate_code":"21","contact_person_first_name":"First","contact_person_last_name":"Last","contact_person_phone":"98989","contact_person_email":"kjskdjk@kjdkaj.com"},{"id":10,"company_name":"Test Company","address1":"abc","address2":"def","po_box":"1234","city_id":2,"email":"lklk@lklk.com","phone":"9898","fax_no":9798,"website":"www.jgjh.com","corporate_code":"22","contact_person_first_name":"First","contact_person_last_name":"Last","contact_person_phone":"98989","contact_person_email":"kjskdjk@kjdkaj.com"},{"id":11,"company_name":"Test Company","address1":"abc","address2":"def","po_box":"1234","city_id":2,"email":"lklk@lklk.com","phone":"9898","fax_no":9798,"website":"www.jgjh.com","corporate_code":"23","contact_person_first_name":"First","contact_person_last_name":"Last","contact_person_phone":"98989","contact_person_email":"kjskdjk@kjdkaj.com"}]
```

If it helps, i get the error before my promise is returned.

Comment: `companySearch` doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$scope.companySearch = function(val) {
    return LeadsService.getCompany(val)
        .then(function(resp) {
            return resp.resp;
        });
};
```

Which returns the promise directly to the typeahead directive. `typeahead` will wait for the data to be resolved.

Comment: No problem. I ran into the same issue

Answer (score 1):

Try with this code for Typeahead asynchronous loading data

```
$scope.companySearch = function(val) {
    return LeadsService.getCompany(val)
        .then(function(resp) {
            return resp.data;
        });
};
```